# Adding the values of 2 similar Counter metrics

Tags: alert, monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am working on creating alert for an api that have 2 instances with the following metric, and updates the metrics value randomly as seen below:

```
instance - testsat1:
some_metric_counter{app="v1-review-some-app", result="failure",} 14.0

instance- testdfw1:
some_metric_counter{app="v1-review-some-app", result="failure",} 6.0
```

My current rule:

```
- alert: someAlertForSomeCounter
    expr: increase(ome_metric_counter{app="v1-review-some-app", result="failure",}[3m]) > 0
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: Some summary
      description: Consolidated value of counter: {{ $value }}
```

Currently the behavior for this rule is that it sends 2 alerts for each instance with its current value of the metric passed into {{ $value }} on the description.

Is there a way to add the 2 values together and pass it to {{ $value }} and alert it only once?

Comment: Do you want to alert if the SUM of the values is greater than 0? Or something else?

Comment: Thats what it does right now, I want to SUM both values of that 2 metrics together

Comment: I didn't understand the difference between what me and you have said. Anyways, "sum(increase(ome_metric_counter{app="v1-review-some-app", result="failure",}[3m])" did not solve your issue?

Comment: That would alert twice for each instance and will not have the SUM of the TWO instances metric values. What I need is a single alert that does have the SUM of the TWO instances metric values.